# Can't add a kick command on Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make a simple discord bot, but I can't seem to be able to create a kick command without getting an error. Here is what it says in the shell:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 29, in on_message
    await message.channel.send('Hello, World!')
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions```
````

Answer (score 1):

It means that your bot doesn't have the *permission* to send messages.

To solve this problem, simply create a new role then either give it `admin permission` or `send messages permission`. Then assign this role to the bot and you'll eventually make that command work.

Comment: Totally worked, thanks!